# Beginning in Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-4

I'm totally new in Prism (Composite Wpf). I want to create messaging module for my application: invisible panel on the top of the main window which appears when I invoke `ShowMessage(string message)` (and disappears after 5 seconds, for instance).

What I've done:

- Create infrastructure project (contains only one interface `IUIMessagesService`)
- Create module project:

  - Project contains user control - it's panel for the message (View)
  - Project contains `UIMessagesService` class, which implements `IUIMessagesService`
  - In module class I did so:

  `public UIMessagesModule(IRegionManager regionManager, IUnityContainer container)
  {
      _regionManager = regionManager;
      _container = container;
  }`

and

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("UIMessagesRegion", typeof(UIMessagesView));
        _container.RegisterType<IUIMessagesService, UIMessagesService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
```

- Create shell project (bootstrapper, shell view with region e.t.c)

**Questions:**

- How can I change properties of my view in class `UIMessagesService` (in this case `RenderTrasform` to show panel)? May be I need define theese properties in view model? How to change view model properties?
- How to execute module methods `ShowMessages` from application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question you can use Event Aggregation 
For second:

you can use ServiceLocator or container to resolve your type

Comment: No,thanks. I've done it. But there are times when I'm not really sure that I do it properly. PRISM doesn't have strict rules.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly you wanted. But you can use wpfextended toolkit busyindicator. This can show on top of your view with a glossy screen and you can control it just by setting or binding IsBusy dependency property.

take a look at example [here](http://elegantcode.com/2011/10/07/extended-wpf-toolkitusing-the-busyindicator/)